how to get the element count of an array that is part of a struct without defines or const fields?
I have a struct that contains an array.
How can I compute the array element count with standard C, when I do not want to resort to defines or const fields?
typedef struct TEXTUREBUCKET {
    long tpage;
    long nVtx;
    D3DTLBUMPVERTEX vtx[2048];
} TEXTUREBUCKET;

static inline size_t TextureBucketVertexCount() {
    return (sizeof(TEXTUREBUCKET) - offsetof(TEXTUREBUCKET, vtx)) / sizeof(D3DTLBUMPVERTEX); // works as long as vtx is the last member
}



sizeof(((TEXTUREBUCKET*)0)->vtx) / sizeof(((TEXTUREBUCKET*)0)->vtx[0]) ?

Isn't that a nullpointer derefence?

@Raildex no, it isn't. sizeof(((TEXTUREBUCKET*)0)->vtx) doesn't dereference anything. The sizeof operator only returns the size of its argument.

The proposed solution does work if D3DTLBUMPVERTEX is a small type, such as char or short

You can accomplish this with the following expression:
sizeof(((TEXTUREBUCKET*)0)->vtx) / sizeof(((TEXTUREBUCKET*)0)->vtx[0]

Note that there is no NULL pointer dereference here because the sizeof operator does not actually evaluate its operand (unless it's a variable length array).  The expression is only parsed to determine its type.
This is spelled out in section 6.5.3.4p2 of the C standard regarding the sizeof operator:

The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
is an integer constant.

